# Greatest multiple of r not greater than x

Tags: ruby, floating-point

Given floats `x` and `r`, what is the best way to get the greatest multiple of `r` not greater than `x`?

**Edit**

Given floats `x` and `r`, what is the best way to get the least multiple of `r` not less than `x`?

---

**Edit**
Two ways that came to mind are follows:

```
x.div(r).*(r)
x-(x.modulo(r))

3.7.div(0.5).*(0.5)   #=> 3.5
3.7-(3.7.modulo(0.5)) #=> 3.5
```

Benchmark results are:

```
require "benchmark/ips"
Benchmark.ips do |b|
  b.report{3.7.div(0.5).*(0.5)}
  b.report{3.7-(3.7.modulo(0.5))}
end

Calculating -------------------------------------
                         70669 i/100ms
                         94162 i/100ms
-------------------------------------------------
                      1951384.0 (±1.3%) i/s -    9822991 in   5.034777s
                      3713013.7 (±1.9%) i/s -   18644076 in   5.023100s
```

If anyone can explain whether there is any difference in accuracy between the two, and why the second one is faster, that would also be great.

An answer that is more accurate/faster is welcome.

Comment: Well it's not really about solving the problem.. :)

Comment: You mean this as integral multiples right?

Comment: Nevermind. Your update shows you're trying to calculate in floats.

Comment: Somehow my question was essential. See your calculation doesn't even produce a float factor: `> 3.7.div(0.5)` => `7`. And modulo is somehow a little inaccurate: `3.7.modulo(0.5) => 0.20000000000000018`

Comment: Per your question the greatest multiple of `0.5` not greater than `3.7` is `3.5` but if `3.7.div(0.5)` actually produces a float, multiplying it with `3.5` should be just roughly the same as `3.7`. But nevermind. I get the target.

Comment: @konsolebox Actually floating-point modulo is always exact. It is `3.7` which is not what you think.

Comment: Anyway, subtraction is always faster than division or multiplication even in machine level so the second version would always win. @PascalCuoq I just showed the output from Ruby. But honestly it's my mistake that I misread the question abut `greatest multiple`.

Comment: @konsolebox When you input or when Ruby prints `0.2`, it doesn't mean 2/10, it means the floating-point value nearest to 2/10. Same for `3.7`. In `3.7.modulo(0.5)`, the modulo operation is exact. But it is not working on 37/10. It is working on a value that is in fact closer to `3.70000000000000018`, but which is also the nearest floating-point value to 37/10.

Comment: @PascalCuoq Interesting. Can you tell me why it's necessary for floats to have `.0000000000000018` just in case the actual stored value is `3.70000000000000018` and not just caused by printing? Or perhaps I misread your answer again sorry..

Comment: @konsolebox For integers, the fact that computer values are stored in binary doesn't make a difference to the user: you can go quite far without noticing that the computer does not work in decimal. But for fractional values, it makes a big difference. The value represented in decimal `0.125` is simpler than the value represented as `0.100`. In fact the latter is not representable exactly at all in binary. Similarly, although 3.7 is simple in decimal, in binary it takes all the available digits of the `double` format to approximate, and even then the representation is not exact.

Comment: @PascalCuoq Thanks I got that quick. :)

Comment: @konsolebox 3.7 is represented in binary as 1 .1101100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011010 * 10^1, and that's only an approximation, because the repeating decimals had to be cut at the end.

Comment: I actually always imagined that floats are always stored accurately as long as numbers don't go in bigger lengths yet but I guess I was wrong. Yeah..

Comment: @konsolebox: everybody kind of understands that floats have limited precision, because there's only 2**64 floats but uncountably infinitely many reals. But the fact that they are represented as binary but written as decimal introduces another problem: it is not immediately obvious that 1/10 has an infinite representation in binary (just like 1/3 has an infinite representation in decimal, but is just 0.1 in ternary). Witness the dozens of "why is 0.1+0.1+0.1+0.1+0.1+0.1+0.1+0.1+0.1+0.1 != 1" questions on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2):

From someone who doesn't know Ruby, an answer regarding the accuracy part of your question:

The modulo floating-point operation is always exact. Therefore `3.7.modulo(0.5)` is exactly what you would expect if you computed using math (assuming you understand that `3.7` is not 37/10 but the floating-point value nearest to that). Therefore `3.7-(3.7.modulo(0.5))` is the floating-point value nearest to the exact result, the best result that you can hope to represent as a floating-point value.

The other alternative in your question, `3.7.div(0.5).*(0.5)`, appears to use what I am going to call an “integral division” operation, `.div`, between floating-point values. This is a great primitive to have. (Not all programming languages have it. This is the first time I encounter it.)

I do not think this integral division operation can always be exact because its ideal result can be too large to be represented exactly as a floating-point number. It is exact (should be exact if correctly implemented) when the result is less than 2<sup>53</sup>, though.

When the result of the integral division in `X.div(Y).*(Y)` is exact, then this sequence of operations also computes the best possible result. The multiplication is the only rounding step.

When the result of the integral division is not exact, then there are two compounding rounding steps, one for the integral division and one for the multiplication, that contribute to make the final error larger. But this only happens if `X` is more than 2<sup>53</sup> times `Y`.

<sub>All values assumed to be positive for simplicity</sub>

Comment: What is "integral division"?

Comment: @sawa It is the name I gave to `.div` in `3.7.div(0.5).*(0.5)`, assuming that `X.div(Y)` returns, as a floating-point value, the largest integer `Q` such that Q * Y is less than or equal to X, because this is the only possibility that makes `x.div(r).*(r)` in your answer work.

Comment: @sawa Note that if `.div` is implemented as floating-point division followed by truncation to integer, then it is not the ideal primitive that I thought it was. The floating-point division can happen to round the mathematical result **up** to the next floating-point value, and this floating-point value can happen to be an integer. If `.div` is implemented as floating-point division followed by truncation, then there is a risk that for some rare inputs, `x.div(r).*(r)` will sometimes return a value larger than `x`. In this case relying on modulo is better.

Answer (score 1):

Pseudocode:

```
multiple = x / r
multiple = int(multi)
max_value = multiple * r
```

I might miss the point here, but why did you tag this as "ruby"?

And (by demand) in ruby:

```
max_value = (x/r).floor * r
```

Comment: I am not looking for pesudocode. And that should answer why I tagged it as ruby.

Comment: @robert, I guess he tagged Ruby because he wants the answer to be done in Ruby? Just a guess ~_~